# With GNome 3 how can I make the second monitor unique to each workspace instead of shared?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

Currently Gnome3 sets my second monitor to be shared across all workspaces. I'd prefer each workspace to have it's own second monitor layout. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it after browsing other questions here. Run **gconf-editor** and under **/apps/mutter/general** untick **workspaces_only_on_primary**.

Update:
The above applies to Gnome 3.0. In Gnome 3.2 (and newer, most probably) the key is in **/desktop/gnome/shell/windows/**.